# how to invoke the webdriver which is declared inside the webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i have declared webdriver inside the saveImage webservice and i am trying to invoke it through webresource. But it is throughing mappableContainer Exception couldnot be mapped to resource. I have tried the following can anyone please help solving this. Thanks.

```
@POST
@Path("/helloworld")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String saveImage(String inputJson) throws IOException,
        JSONException,
        AWTException {
JSONObject inputJsonObj = new JSONObject(inputJson);
String ipAddress = (String) inputJsonObj.get("username");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"C:\\seleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
return ("opened selenium successfully");
}
```

Now I am calling this webservice through the webresource from another class. the path mentioned is correct.

```
JSONObject apiJson = new JSONObject();
apiJson.put("username", "userName");
String path = "http://localhost:8585/Server/startpage/helloworld";
WebResource webResource = client.resource(path);
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
                .post(ClientResponse.class, apiJson.toString());
```

else Is there any other way to call the webresource inside where selenium is declared?